# nodejitsu deploy: scons command not found

Tags: python, node.js, scons, nodejitsu, libxml-js

I am trying to deploy my node app using nodejitsu, but receive an error when running 'jitsu deploy'.

The relevant error lines are:

```
> libxmljs@0.4.1 preinstall /root/tmp/tmp-31613c7bs0y8/build/package/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/libxmljs
> make node

make: scons: Command not found
make: *** [node] Error 127
npm http 200 https://registry.nodejitsu.com/css-stringify
npm http 200 https://registry.nodejitsu.com/css-parse
npm http 200 https://registry.nodejitsu.com/is-promise/-/is-promise-1.0.1.tgz

> libxmljs@0.4.1 preuninstall /root/tmp/tmp-31613c7bs0y8/build/package/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/libxmljs
> make clean

make: scons: Command not found
make: *** [clean] Error 127
npm http GET https://registry.nodejitsu.com/css-stringify/-/css-stringify-1.0.5.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.nodejitsu.com/css-parse/-/css-parse-1.0.4.tgz
npm WARN continuing anyway libxmljs@0.4.1 preuninstall: `make clean`
npm WARN continuing anyway Exit status 2
npm ERR! libxmljs@0.4.1 preinstall: `make node`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.4.1 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the libxmljs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     make node
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls libxmljs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System SunOS 5.11
npm ERR! command "node" "/opt/local/bin/npm" "install" "--loglevel=http"
npm ERR! cwd /root/tmp/tmp-31613c7bs0y8/build/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

So I installed scons as described here: http://www.scons.org/doc/2.3.1/HTML/scons-user.html#idm14220792

Basically install the tar file, open it, and run "sudo python setup.py install"

Now when I run 'scons -v' it returns:

```
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine path: ['/usr/local/lib/scons-2.3.4/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2014 The SCons Foundation
```

But when I run 'jitsu deploy' again, I see the same errors.
Is scons still not installed correctly? Is this an issue with nodejitsu, scons, or libxmljs?

Comment: SCons seems to have been installed in "/usr/local/lib"...so have you checked the location of the SCons script with "which scons", and ensured that its folder (probably something like "/usr/local/bin") is in the PATH for the make environment that gets used for the build/deploy?

Comment: Thanks dirkbaechle, I think that's probably it. "which scons" does indeed show /usr/local/bin/scons, but I'm not sure how to check the PATH for the make environment that gets used for deploy, any ideas how to do so?

Comment: No, sorry...I'm not familiar with this build/deploy environment that you're using. All I can say is that it doesn't look like an SCons-specific problem to me.

Comment: Yes, I believe it's a libxmljs problem. I tried deploying using Heroku as well and it also yielded the same errors with "make node" and "make clean" in libxmljs. I may open a separate question as the problem doesn't seem to be specific to nodejitsu nor scons, but just about the make environment of libxmljs. Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're using a very old version of `libxmljs` ([v0.4.1 is from 2010](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/releases/tag/0.4.1)), one that was designed to work with a much older version of node (e.g. v0.6.x and older). As of this writing, the latest stable version of `libxmljs` is v0.13.0, so you should try updating the module.

Comment: I upgraded my version of libxmljs and now running 'npm list -g | grep libxmljs' yields 'libxmljs@0.13.0', but I'm still seeing the same error with scons.

Comment: Don't install it globally. Just do `npm install libxmljs` in your project's root directory.

Comment: I installed it within my project's root directory as well but I see the same errors. I believe dirkbaechle was right in his comment to my issue that scons is probably not in the PATH for the make environment that gets used for deploy, but I'm unsure how to check or add it there if necessary.